# For Loop with averaging

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am trying to use a for loop to get prompts to appear but how would I get the average from the loop? when it loops a var with a propmt in it would it be like             var student[0],var student[1] ect how are they defined so i can average them?

```
<html>

<head>
<title>
    for
</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
    Average your marks:
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Start</button>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var Avg = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // this part makes the prompt below repeat 5 times 
                                       // but how would i multiply them.
            var Student = prompt("Enter your mark.  ");

            Avg +=                     // no clue what to do here
        }
        window.alert(Avg);
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The input when i open the page, it repeats the var Student = prompt("enter your marks"). it repeats 5 times like i want it but how would i multiply the 5 repeated prompts and divide by 5 to get the average? @uzaif

Comment: Sum all the `Student` values and then divide by 5 after loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
    var sum = 0; // should be initialized to 0 not ""
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var mark = prompt("Enter your mark: ");
        sum += Number(mark); // sum the marks (convert mark to number because prompt return a string)
    }
    var avg = sum / 5; // the average is the sum divided by the number of marks which is 5
    alert("Your average is: " + avg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you are very helpful!

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw That will be another story. I used `Number` just so the `+` won't be regarded as concatenation!

Comment: @MichaelWong thats exactly why i said what i said. if it returns nan and trying to add a number with nan..... anyway you seem happy with the answer so all good. i was just considering validation first.

Comment: You can have a default value for prompt

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is increment the Avg variable with what you have entered from the prompt. Then get the average by dividing the total from the amount of prompts that will be shown.

```
var Avg = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var Student = prompt("Enter your mark.  ");
    Avg += Student;
}
window.alert(Avg/5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This also prompts the user for what number student they are entering the mark for and if the user does not enter anything it considers that students mark as zero:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to enter the 5 student's marks</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Start</button>

<p id="Average"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var sum = 0;
    var students = 5;
    for (var i = 1; i <= students; i++) { 
      var mark = prompt("Please the mark for student " + i, 0);
      sum += Number(mark)
    }
    document.getElementById("Average").innerHTML =
        "The average mark was: " + (sum/students);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```